# Why do my variables change out of nowhere?

Tags: c++

We've received a project in school to program an algorithm in C++ that finds a solution to the 8 Queens Problem. I still consider myself a beginner in programming, so I might not be using the most effective tools. I used one two-dimensional array (8x8) for storing the stats themselves, and another one to store some sources, so when it gets to a point where it can't go further, it only deletes the right values.

My issue here is, when compiled, at some point it changes some variables from the source array to 2, when it really shouldn't. It even does that when I remove all of the equations related to the array. I haven't seen anything like this before. I always make an output of both arrays to check how it's working. Could anyone tell me why those few variables change?

PS: if you ever get to compiling this you can move the program to the next step by pressing any button.

I'm using Code::Blocks 16.01 with GNU GCC Compiler.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int board[8][8], queens_placed=0, sources[8][8], line_progress[8];
    //values: free:0, occupied:1, in-range:2;
    //board[vertical][horizontal]
    for (int i=0;i<8;i++) {  //setting some values
        for (int j=0;j<8;j++) {
            board[i][j]=0;
            sources[i][j]=9;
            cout<<board[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
        line_progress[i]=-1;
    }
    while (queens_placed!=8) {
        bool full=true; //this detects if there are more possibilities
        for (int i=0;i<8;i++) {
            if (board[queens_placed][i]==0 && i>line_progress[queens_placed]) {
                board[queens_placed][i]=1; //if there is free space then place the queen and allocate the relevant spaces
                line_progress[queens_placed]=i;
                sources[queens_placed][i]=8;
                for (int j=queens_placed+1;j<8;j++) {
                    board[j][i]=2;
                    if (sources[j][i]==9) {sources[j][i]=queens_placed;}
                }
                for (int j=i+1;j<8;j++) {
                    board[queens_placed][j]=2;
                    if (sources[queens_placed][j]==9) {sources[queens_placed][j]=queens_placed;}
                }
                int alt1=queens_placed+1;
                for (int j=i+1;j<8;j++) {
                    board[alt1][j]=2;
                    if (sources[alt1][j]==9) {sources[alt1][j]=queens_placed;}
                    alt1++;
                }
                int alt2=queens_placed+1;
                for (int j=i-1;j>0;j--) {
                    board[alt2][j]=2;
                    if (sources[alt2][j]==9) {sources[alt2][j]=queens_placed;}
                    alt2++;
                }
                queens_placed++;
                i=8;
                full=false;
            }
        }
        if (full==true) { //this is when we have to step back a little
            line_progress[queens_placed]=-1;
            queens_placed--;
            for (int i=0;i<8;i++) {
                if (board[queens_placed][i]==1) {
                    board[queens_placed][i]=0;
                    sources[queens_placed][i]=9;
                }
            }
            for (int i=0;i<8;i++) {
                for (int j=0;j<8;j++) {
                    if (sources[i][j]==queens_placed) {
                        sources[i][j]=9;
                        board[i][j]=0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        system("cls"); //the ckecking part
        cout<<"Table status (-:empty spot, O:Queen's place, X:unavailable spot):"<<endl;
        for (int i=7;i>=0;i--) {
            for (int j=0;j<8;j++) {
                if (board[i][j]==0) {cout<<"- ";}
                if (board[i][j]==1) {cout<<"O ";}
                if (board[i][j]==2) {cout<<"X ";}
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
        cout<<endl<<"Sources:"<<endl;
        for (int i=7;i>=0;i--) {
            for (int j=0;j<8;j++) {
                cout<<sources[i][j]<<" ";
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
        int a=getch();
        while (!a) {}
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You realize you set the value of your board to be `2` in four different places, right? Why do you *not* expect their values to be `2` after you do this? You'll have to elaborate more on the unexpected behavior you're seeing.

Comment: The board array, which I'm making equal to 2 in four places isn't the problem. The second array (int source[8][8]) is the problem. Even when I remove all of the value settings for the source array, it still gets changed while compiling.

Comment: Yeah, you're going OB (a lot). See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of code in your post, and it's not totally clear what *exactly* you're hoping to fix (there's a lot of issues), but one bug you certainly have is that you're going out of bounds:

```
int alt1=queens_placed+1;
for (int j=i+1;j<8;j++) {
    board[alt1][j]=2;
    if (sources[alt1][j]==9) {sources[alt1][j]=queens_placed;}
    alt1++;
}
```

The invariant is that `queens_placed != 8`, or the loop breaks. You increment it by one each loop, but at some point we will have `queens_placed == 7`, meaning that `alt1 == 7 + 1 == 8`, meaning that `board[alt1][j]=2` is out of bounds (and so is `sources[alt1][j]`). It could very well be that `board[alt1][j]=2` is blasting over your `sources` array. Furthermore, you're doing `alt1++` without checking what it is...

Some proof as opposed to mere conjecture (copied your code into `test.cpp` and removed the windows stuff and the `getch()` call, compiled with `g++ -g test.cpp -o test`, `-g` allows debug):

```
(lldb) n
Process 78941 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = step over
    frame #0: 0x0000000100001901 test`main at test.cpp:38
   35                   }
   36                   int alt1=queens_placed+1;
   37                   for (int j=i+1;j<8;j++) {
-> 38                       board[alt1][j]=2;
   39                       if (sources[alt1][j]==9) {sources[alt1][j]=queens_placed;}
   40                       alt1++;
   41                   }
Target 0: (test) stopped.
(lldb) p alt1
(int) $18 = 8
```

**Recommendation (take it or leave it):** Start with something smaller that you *know* works. It's pretty hard to reason about what's going on in your program (there's a lot of variables floating around, things are referenced all over the place, little locality, cyclomatic complexity is extremely high, etc). Build little functions (5-20 lines), and test each of those. Clearing the board, checking the board is a solution, and composing the "next" board seem like good functions to have. Then compose your functions to solve your problem.

HTH.

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into these tomorrow, I've closed this project for today.